# Can Haml be used in Java web apps?

Tags: java, haml

I hear about Haml as a templating engine mostly in the Ruby world. Can it also be used in Java projects?

Comment: i'd like to see as well, sucks that there isn't an implementation yet

Comment: Get Updated. 
Not that I'm that a Java Fan, but I'm working now with a Java Team and they do deserve the respect :) See comment by SztupY

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a list of Haml implementations [on the Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haml#Implementations). At the moment, there isn't one for Java.

## Update

There has been a Java implementation for a few years now : https://github.com/raymyers/JHaml

Comment: There is one now on that page, called JHaml.

Answer (score 11):

2 years after this question was asked (:P) there are:

- scaml -
  http://scalate.fusesource.org/documentation/scaml-reference.html
- jade -
  http://scalate.fusesource.org/documentation/jade.html

Comment: Scalate project is for Scala and not JAVA.

Comment: downvoting for that is interesting considering that scala runs on the jvm and interops with java just fine.

Comment: But it is not about the JVM, using Scalate requires knowing Scala and using an app framework of Scala like Scalatra.

Comment: I'm going to cast my vote with the downvoters here.  Scala is fun and all, but that doesn't make it Java, and the fact that it runs on Java or can be used in conjunction with Java is like saying you can embed assembly language in C, and C compiles to machine language, therefore C is assembly language.  The original question was about a Java implementation.

Comment: Did you even both to read scalate's documentation for how to use jade? http://scalate.github.io/scalate/documentation/user-guide.html#using_scalate_as_servlet_filter_in_your_web_application There is no scala involved.

Answer (score 10):

It seems someone started a [project](http://github.com/raymyers/JHaml) for Java.

Comment: Get Updated. 
Not that I'm that a Java Fan, but I'm working now with a Java Team and they do deserve the respect :)

Answer (score 3):

Scalate can be integrated with [Spring](http://scalate.fusesource.org/documentation/spring-mvc.html)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps through [JRuby](http://jruby.codehaus.org/)?

Answer (score 0):

planning to add HAML support in [JPublish](http://code.google.com/p/jpublish/). It will use JRuby.

Answer (score 0):

Use JRuby!
How to is in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751479/sass-implementation-for-java/4448937#4448937) answer.

Answer (score -1):

HAML is dependent on Ruby. I know there is a Python clone of HAML, not sure about Java.

Although, SASS/Compass are language agnostic.

Comment: No it's not. There is HAML for PHP like https://github.com/arnaud-lb/MtHaml and https://github.com/mervick/yii2-mthaml