# CSS selector issue for multiple elements

Tags: css, css-selectors

I thought I had my CSS down fairly well but I cannot seem to figure out why this problem occurs. I must be doing something wrong.

So if I want to select multiple elements that are children to a div I could write:

```
#mydiv > input, label{

}
```

Am I correct? I thought this to  be true until I realized that other inputs and labels in my site were inheriting these CSS properties even though they were not in the div called #mydiv.  To fix the issue I had to use:

```
#mydiv > input, #mydiv > label {

}
```

But I am pretty sure that this is not the quickest way to do so. I tried checking the [Selector Page](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html) on W3.org but they do not give an example for my situation.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Am I correct?

No. [The grouping selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#grouping) (comma) has the lowest precedence, so you cannot use it to select multiple elements that are children of a div using this selector:

```
#mydiv > input, label
```

The most concise selector is the one that you found on your own:

```
#mydiv > input, #mydiv > label
```

---

You can DRY things up a bit using nested rules in [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) or [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/), though that does introduce a dependency in your code and/or build process.

Comment: can I use sass without ruby? my employer does not normally like to use ruby. don't ask why..lol

Comment: Yes, absolutely. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4167424/how-can-i-run-sass-without-installing

Answer (score 1):

Your second snippet is the simplest way to do it with pure CSS. The comma `,` separates isolated CSS selectors, so that's why you needed to begin each with `#mydiv` for both selectors.

You could use something like [LESS](http://lesscss.org/), which would allow [nested rules](http://lesscss.org/#-client-side-usage). Non-germane example:

```
#header {
  h1 {
    font-size: 26px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  p { font-size: 12px;
    a { text-decoration: none;
      &:hover { border-width: 1px }
    }
  }
}
```

But you're probably better off with pure CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Your second method is good

```
#mydiv > input, #mydiv > label {

}
```

If you wanted to somehow do this without using multiple selectors separated by a comma, you could use a class name for both your input and label elements

```
.your-class-name {

}
```

or if for some reason input and label were the only two types of child elements for #mydiv, then you could use the universal selector like this:

```
#mydiv > * {

}
```