# Cleanest way to run susy, compass, and sass within jruby-complete?

Tags: eclipse, ant, jruby, compass-sass, susy-compass

why can jruby find `require 'susy'` in my compass config.rb, but `@import 'susy'` within *.scss files produces the issue:

```
 [java]     error Web Content/common/sass/base/foundation_de_DE.scss (Line 9: File to import not found or unreadable: susy.
        [java] Load paths:
        [java]   <removed>/Web Content/common/sass
```

My existing application wants to start using a responsive design on the front end.  However, installing ruby / compass on all the developer's machines, integration environments, performance environments and production would kill the initiative.

per this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1751479/176818), and this [simplified tutorial](http://caueguerra.com/tutorial-using-sass-in-a-java-project) I used our current Ant build.xml to make some targets using jRuby.

[gems in a jar](http://blog.nicksieger.com/articles/2009/01/10/jruby-1-1-6-gems-in-a-jar/) trick to so that I don't need to install ruby everywhere:
downloaded jruby-complete-1.6.8.jar per [latest jruby has relative path issue as of 2013.03.20](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/issues/235)

```
java -jar jruby-complete-1.6.8.jar -S gem install -i ./susy susy  
jar uf jruby-complete-1.6.8.jar -C susy .  
java -jar jruby-complete-1.6.8.jar -S gem list
```

ant target used during the build process:

```
 <target name="compass.compile">
     <java classname="org.jruby.Main" fork="true" failonerror="true" classpathref="jruby.classpath">  
                <arg line="${basedir}/compile.rb ${basedir} compile ${basedir}"/>   
            </java>
     </target>
```

ant target used by Eclipse based IDE to 'auto-compile' when a user saves a scss file.  [Instructions to have Eclipse 'auto-build' scss files (start at step #5)](http://wirelesswombat.com/2012/06/17/automatically-compling-sass-compass-in-eclipse-zend-studio/)

```
<target name="compass.dev">
        <path id="jruby.classpath">
            <fileset dir="../../../release/lib/arch/jruby">
                <include name="jruby-complete.jar"/>
            </fileset>            
        </path>
        <java classname="org.jruby.Main" fork="true" failonerror="true" classpathref="jruby.classpath">  
            <arg line="${basedir}/compile.rb ${basedir} compile ${basedir}"/>  
        </java>
    </target>
```

Finally, here is the 'compile.rb' used by the ant target:

```
Dir.entries(ARGV[0]).each do |lib|  
    $LOAD_PATH.unshift "#{ARGV[0]}/#{lib}/lib"  
end

require 'rubygems'
require 'compass' 
require 'susy'
require 'compass/exec'  

exit Compass::Exec::SubCommandUI.new([ARGV[1], ARGV[2], "-q"]).run!
```

and the config.rb used by compass:

```
 # Require any additional compass plugins here.  
# Set this to the root of your project when deployed:
require 'susy'

http_path = "./Web Content/"  
css_dir = "./Web Content/common/sass-output-css/"  
sass_dir = "./Web Content/common/sass/"
add_import_path  "./Web Content/sass"  
images_dir = "./Web Content/common/images/"  
javascripts_dir = "./Web Content/common/js/widgets"  
# To enable relative paths to assets via compass helper functions. Uncomment:  
#relative_assets = true
```

and finally, trying to use susy in an scss file:

```
@import 'reset'; 
@import 'utilities';
@import 'baseColorVariables'; 
@import 'font';  
@import 'susy'; 


$total-columns: 12; 
$column-width: 4em; 
$gutter-width: 1em; 
$grid-padding: 1em;
.magic-container { @include container; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*update* as of 2013.03.20, this works. but it may not be the cleanest way to get Susy / compass on 'rubyless' machines. does anyone have anything cleaner?

found it.  compass is not in the sass load path, nor is susy actually while running under a 'gems in a jar' jruby solution.  Thank you Henning Petersen, and [your post](http://henningpetersen.com/post/7/integrating-compass-style-sass-into-tapestry)
specifically:

> JRuby has quite a brilliant abstraction from the file-based way of all things Ruby, so most things keep working when packaged into a JAR. A file inside a JAR has a path roughly like this: /path/to/jar/gems.jar!file/in/jar/script.rb. JRuby keeps relative files and everything working when using JARs, with one great BUT: There is no way to do such a thing as a directory listing inside a JAR file. That's right, everything that reads directory listings is now broken.

I altered compass's frameworks.rb (not a fan) so it's directory listing call failure does not stop compass from loading itself into the sass load path:

```
Compass::Frameworks.discover(:defaults)
Compass::Frameworks.register_directory(File.join(Compass.base_directory, 'frameworks/compass'))
Compass::Frameworks.register_directory(File.join(Compass.base_directory, 'frameworks/blueprint'))
```

which changes a *.scss auto-compile request to:

```
Syntax error: File to import not found or unreadable: susy.
              Load paths:
                <removed>/Web Content/common/sass
                file:<removed>/release/lib/arch/jruby/jruby-complete.jar!/gems/compass-0.12.2/frameworks/compass/stylesheets
                file:<removed>/release/lib/arch/jruby/jruby-complete.jar!/gems/compass-0.12.2/frameworks/blueprint/stylesheets
```

ok, now we need to get susy into the load path. adding this line to compass's `config.rb` does not work, though I wish it did: `add_import_path  "../../../release/lib/arch/jruby/jruby-complete.jar!gems/susy-1.0.7/sass"`

[Henning Petersen also caught this, and it was again because of directory listing calls withing the jruby jar](http://henningpetersen.com/post/7/integrating-compass-style-sass-into-tapestry)  altered compass's `configuration/adapters.rb` and Sass's `importers/filesystem.rb`. Altering all those files is dirtier to maintain than I am comfortable with, and already the posting is out of date regarding compass && sass.

So I pulled the sass directory out of the jar, which let the compass's `add_import_path` work as intended.  The cleanest solution I have so far is manually appending to the `gem/compass-0.12.2/lib/frameworks.rb`:

```
Compass::Frameworks.register_directory(File.join(Compass.base_directory, 'frameworks/compass'))
Compass::Frameworks.register_directory(File.join(Compass.base_directory, 'frameworks/blueprint'))
```

and then adding this line to the compass project's config.rb (whole file provided):

```
 # Require any additional compass plugins here.  
# Set this to the root of your project when deployed:
require 'susy'

http_path = "./Web Content/"  
css_dir = "./Web Content/common/sass-output-css/"  
sass_dir = "./Web Content/common/sass/"
add_import_path  "./Web Content/susy-1.0.7-read-only"  
images_dir = "./Web Content/common/images/"  
javascripts_dir = "./Web Content/common/js/widgets"  
# To enable relative paths to assets via compass helper functions. Uncomment:  
#relative_assets = true
```

which led to the RAD / eclipse builder scss auto-compile ant target to spit out:

```
compass.dev:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 16 seconds
```